# Client-side vs server-side templating for large enterprise applications

Tags: jquery-templates, templating, client-side-templating

What makes most sense for large enterprise applications involving several jsps and many transactions (like a commercial banking application or a healthcare application with huge amounts of data) w.r.t templating? Is it just a matter of personal choice or is there a strong reason to lean towards server-side templating?

Answer (score 0):

Client-side templating is more matter of UI and should not be confused with backend transactions in any way. When your site does something it is still doing HTTP POST which is processed by the server logic. I saw the development more like a natural continuum to build easier to use web enabled by the modern browsers and Javascript engines.

You might find some more info here:

https://github.com/leonidas/transparency/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions